# How do I add an if-condition to a Rails.logger.silence do-loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I would like to silence the logs of a particular controller under a specific condition. For @product there is a `@product.sensitive` (boolean) attribute. I would like the #show-controller to not log anything if `@product.sensitive == true`. This is how it is solved for silencing all logs **without** a condition (which works fine for me):

```
def show
  Rails.logger.silence do
    if @product.price > 0
      # Do this
    else
      # Do that
    end
  end
end
```

But what if I now want the Rails.lgger.silence to be conditional of @product.sensitive == true ? I can't do:

```
 def show
    if @product.sensitive
          Rails.logger.silence do
    end
            if @product.price > 0
              # Do this
            else
              # Do that
            end
          end
    if @product.sensitive
    end
    end
end
```

So, wow do I solve this? I guess there are two different solutions: either there is a way to activate the loop only under the condition that `@product.sensitive == true` or by simply disabling the logger in any other way (and reactivate it at the end of the controller).

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could throw the "real" code in a lambda and run it inside/outside `Rails.logger.silence` as appropriate:

```
def show
  the_real_work = -> do
    if @product.price > 0
      # Do this
    else
      # Do that
    end
  end
  if @product.sensitive
    Rails.logger.silence(&the_real_work)
  end
    the_real_work[]
  end
end
```

or use a separate method:

```
# This would probably be private in real life.
def the_real_show
  if @product.price > 0
    # Do this
  else
    # Do that
  end
end

def show
  if @product.sensitive
    Rails.logger.silence { the_real_show }
    # or Rails.logger.silence(&method(:the_real_show))
  end
    the_real_show
  end
end
```

If `@product` is (or can be) created in a `before_action` before `#show` is called, you could turn things inside out:

```
# Of somewhere private...
def silence_logging
  Rails.logger.silence { yield }
end

def needs_silencing?
  action_name == 'show' && @product.sensitive
end
```

And then hook up the silence.

```
before_action :whatever_already_loads_the_product
around_action :silence_logging, if: :needs_silencing?
```

Unfortunately you can't mix `:if` and `:only` options since `:if` overrides `:only`, otherwise you could say things like `if: :sensitive_product, only: :show`.

Comment: I couldn't get the lambda version to work for the silenced verson but the separate method worked fine. Thanks!